# Cite author and title for monographs

Tags: latex, citations, biblatex

for a university paper I have to write an essay. The professor has percise instructions how to cite. For monograph books, he wants the author and the title in the footnotes.

I tried to use biblatex for this, but could not manage to get it to work

My minimal reproducible example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{test}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{100}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{100}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{100}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ 
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},             
} 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is a minimal reproducible example. \footcite{adams1995hitchhiker}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which outputs:
[footnote image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vl7kH.png)

Now i want to add the title of the book too (in this case The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy) in the footnote

Any idea how to implement this?

Comment: Please make a [mre] instead of this code fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if the `authortitle` style would be closer to your requirements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{test}

\usepackage[style=authortitle,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99, uniquename=false]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{knuth,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The {\TeX} book},
  date         = 1984,
  maintitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volume       = {A},
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  sortyear     = {1984-1},
  sorttitle    = {Computers & Typesetting A},
  indexsorttitle= {The TeXbook},
  indextitle   = {\protect\TeX book, The},
  shorttitle   = {\TeX book}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{100}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{100}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{100}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ 
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},             
} 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is a minimal reproducible example. \footcite{knuth}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]